# why is my transaction not rolling back?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qt4

```
 try
    {
       qDebug()<<connector.db.transaction();
        QSqlQuery *query=new QSqlQuery(connector.db);
                query->prepare("UPDATE partstore SET Name =? ,ID=?,SellingPrice=?, Quantity=? WHERE ID=?");
                query->addBindValue(ui->lineEdit_Name->text());
                query->addBindValue(ui->lineEdit_ID->text());
                query->addBindValue(ui->lineEdit_SP->text());
                query->addBindValue(ui->lineEdit_Quantity->text());
                query->addBindValue(prevID);

                QSqlQuery *query2=new QSqlQuery(connector.db);
                query2->prepare("UPDATE partstock SET ID=? WHERE ID=?");
                query2->addBindValue(ui->lineEdit_ID->text());
                query2->addBindValue(prevID);

      qDebug()<<  connector.db.commit();
        if(!query->exec())
        {
            throw 1;
        }
        qDebug()<<"q1executed";
        throw 1;
        if(!query2->exec())
        {
            throw 1;
        }
        qDebug()<<"q2executed";
         prevID=ui->lineEdit_ID->text();
         ID=ui->lineEdit_ID->text();

    }
    catch (...)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Executrion failed";
       qDebug() <<connector.db.rollback();
    }
```

using throw 1; in between the query should rollback the transaction but it is not ,why?
i am using throw 1 between the two query just to check if the rollback properly works or not and the rollback is not working  but execution failed is debugged.

Comment: Why are you *commiting* in the code? Are you sure the rollback fails for the query you're currently working on, and not for the previous (if this is in a loop or done after another query)? Also, if you're testing and debugging, why not step through the code in a debugger? Or at least throw proper (and **different!**) exceptions so you know exactly which of the throws you're catching? Lastly, using the "catch all" clause when catching exceptions is usually considered bad style or a sign of a bad design.

Comment: i think commiting in the code will create a save point so that if rollback is called the database will be changed to my initial commit.

Comment: That's what the [`transaction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#transaction) call does. Also read about [`rollback`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#rollback) and [`commit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#commit). And more about databases and transactions in general.

Comment: i am confused about rollback and commit. Documentation does not seem to help

Comment: That's why I suggested you try to find and read more about how it works more generally. There are tons of documentation all over the Internet, and even more in book-form.

Comment: However, as a quick introduction here's the basics: You start a transaction. This transaction ends when you either commit it or roll it back. Everything you do while the transaction is active is part of the commit or rollback. And that's about it.

Comment: thanx for ur help :]